# Arduino keeps on restarting after serial communication

Tags: python, arduino-uno

```
Good day
```

I have a python code which is connected to my arduino using serial communication and 
after i run the command (opening LED) the LED will turn on for about 2 seconds and after that the arduino will restart and go to the default which is the LED is off. But it runs perfectly in serial monitor

```
python code
 time.sleep(2) 
        ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600)

        if 'lights on' in voice:   #after sending this part the LED will turn on for about 2 sec and then turning off again
            ser.write(1)   

        if 'lights off' in voice:
            ser.write(2)

        time.sleep(2)    
        ser.close()    


arduino code:

byte incomingByte = 0; // for incoming serial data
int Relay4 = 13;
void setup() {

Serial.begin(9600); // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
pinMode(Relay4,OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(Relay4, HIGH);
}

void loop()
{

if(Serial.available())
{
  incomingByte = Serial.read();
  Serial.println(incomingByte,DEC);
  switch(incomingByte){
  case 49:
  digitalWrite(Relay4,LOW);
  break;
  case 50:
  digitalWrite(Relay4,HIGH);
  break;
  default:
  break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Uno resets on new USB connection.

Answer (score 0):

remove ser.close() and do something to prevent python from exit like

```
while(True):
    pass
```

Comment: it has the same result.

Comment: how it seem like?
did your python program exit?